# Pick a character and output the whole word problem with reversing part of the code

Tags: c#, char, reverse

I got assignment in String "Alena has 2 hands" pick a char (num) and if it is a char in a word write out the whole word.

I wrote out characters after and before the letter until it hit either space, dot or first character of array but part of it is reversed and I am not sure how to reverse it in this code.

I picked "num = 2" so char 'e' so I want to get back "Alena". I tried this

```
static void firstWord(String s1, int num)
{
    char[] sentence = s1.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(sentence[i]);
    }
    int y = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    for (int s = 0; s < s1.Length; s++)
    {
        if (sentence[num - y] == ' ' || sentence[num - y] == '.' || 
            sentence[num - y] == sentence[0])
        {
            if (sentence[num - y] == sentence[0])
            {
                Console.Write(sentence[0]);
                s = s1.Length;
            }
            continue;
        }
        Console.Write(sentence[num - y]);
        y++;
    }
    int x = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        if (sentence[num + x] == ' ' || sentence[num + x] == '.')
        {
            continue;
        }
        Console.Write(sentence[num + x]);
        x++;
    }
}
```

And the output is  "elAna" so I need to reverse the "elA" to "Ale" to make it work but I am pretty lost. I think i know how basic reversing works but not sure how to use it in this case.
Or if you have way to make it using a different way I dont have a problem to make it all over again.

If possible without regex, split and Distinct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with that loop, but if you are simply trying to get the first word in a string with space as delimiter, that matches the character at a specific spot in the string, then you can use the following linq statement

1. Split the string with space as the delimiter
2. Get the First word that has the character you want to search for
3. Return the word you found or null if none found.

```
    static string firstWord(string s1, int num)
    {
        return s1.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(s1.ElementAt(num)));
    }
```

You can use this in your main class like this,

```
    string input = "Alena has 2 hands";
    Console.WriteLine(firstWord(input, 2));
```

**Output**

```
Alena
```